# How to remove whitespace or '%2520' and plus sign with hyphen (-) in URL?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mysqli

I am using MySQL query for displaying database record and before using mod_rewrite my url structure was this - http://127.0.0.1/medical-word-2.php?query=Choreic%20Abasia

And after using mod_rewrite command in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

    #redirect all old URLs to the new rewritten URL
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+medical-word-2\.php\?query=([^&\ ]+)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

    #rewrite folder path 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ medical-word-2.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Structure of url is - http://127.0.0.1/Choreic%2520Abasia

But now I want this url structure – http://127.0.0.1/choreic-abasia

I want to remove ‘%2520’ from url with ‘-’ . Is there any way to achieve this URL structure?

Comment: Is it only %2520 that you want to replace or any % followed by decimal numbers?

Comment: i only want to remove %2520

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace("/%2520|\+/gm", "-", urlstring);`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7tB9rR/1/)

`%2520` matches %2520 literally

`|` means "or"

`\+` matches +

So + or %2520 get replaced with a hyphen

Comment: can you please write complete code for me using info given by me in question, i am beginner.

Comment: I'm not familiar with .htaccess, but this part is just PHP. Just use the `preg_replace` line I provided for you and replace "urlstring" with whatever variable you're using for your URL.